# MS-SQL CHARINDEX fails to find string

Tags: sql-server

I amm using MS-SQL EXPRESS 2012 (no full-text-indexing) and while I can get results when using LIKE on several tables when searching for a keyword using my search form, I cannot get LIKE, CHARINDEX or PATINDEX to find for example, "34", when searching the Skillset column that is comprised of data that looks like...

```
23, 34, 78
```

Have tried the following:

```
Select CHARINDEX('" + strKeyword + "', Skillset) > 0
Select Skillset LIKE '%" + strKeyword + "%'
Select Skillset LIKE '%" + Replace(strKeyword, "'", "''") + "%'
```

Otherwise the third line works on all other columns. The Skillset column is formatted as varchar(150) just like the other columns containing searchable data.

Why doesn't it work with numbers in a column that is storing array type data?

Comment: This isn't doing what you want because you are looking at the string literal %" + strKeyword + "% instead of the column that you think you are looking for. But it also looks like you have delimited data that you are trying to find. You need to provide table definitions, sample data and desired output so others can understand your question here.

Comment: What are the full SELECT statements you are trying to run? None of the SELECT statements are valid as shown. Perhaps you are trying to simplify them, but in doing so we are not getting a full understanding of your situation.

Comment: First off, I am trying to help you here. It is difficult to diagnose the issue because you have multiple layers of issues. The conditions in your SELECT statements must be in a WHERE clause. What table is Skillset coming from? That needs to be part of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your double-quotes are causing you issues. Try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3cd8cf790a3450920b344a458c841ffa)...

```
CREATE TABLE Skills
(
    ID INT
  , Skillset VARCHAR(150)
);

INSERT INTO Skills (ID, Skillset) VALUES (1, '23, 34, 78')
INSERT INTO Skills (ID, Skillset) VALUES (1, '23, 78');

DECLARE @strKeyword VARCHAR(15);
SET @strKeyword = '34';

SELECT * FROM Skills WHERE CHARINDEX(@strKeyword, Skillset) > 0;
SELECT * FROM Skills WHERE Skillset LIKE '%' + @strKeyword + '%'
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your third statement, so I don't have working version of this, but this should get you going.

I tried:

```
rsSearch.Source = "DECLARE @strJobSkillset VARCHAR(15); SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE Skillset LIKE '%' + @strJobSkillset + '%' AND (Jobs.Title LIKE '%" + Replace(rsSearch__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "%' OR Jobs.Summary LIKE '%" + Replace(rsSearch__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "%' OR Jobs.Description LIKE '%" + Replace(rsSearch__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "%' ) and Jobs.Active = '1' ORDER BY Jobs.Title ASC"
```

Comment: I added the DECLARE and both examples run without error, but still no result found.

Comment: You added the DECLARE where? If you click on the link I provided, you can run the code in my answer and see that it does return the one row that contains 34.

Comment: See your answer, I added it there.

Comment: You editing my answer makes for an odd situation. If i reject it, you will think I don't agree or am whining. If I accept it (which I did) it doesn't make sense because it isn't clear what portion of my answer is mine and what is yours.

Comment: In the code you added, what are value are you assigning to @strKeyword?

Comment: The database record = "23, 34, 78" and my keyword is "34". Btw the edit on your answer is only temporary as I couldn't post it anywhere else at the time. You can remove it no problem.

Comment: What is your complete code with the variable assignment? The @strstrKeyword in the code you added to my answer would be an issue if that is actually what you have, but maybe that is just a typo.

Comment: I would recommend getting your SQL working directly on SQL Server first eliminating conditions in your where clause until you get data and then add them back to isolate which one is causing you an issue. Maybe you have already done that. In any case, I am clearly not help. I'm out.

Comment: It works without this new condition, so no problem there. The problem, or lack of response, from this new condition is what I need to solve.